# how to put value on progress bar when data is huge in php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a progress of data processed (in backend )on progress bar (on front).

For this 2 things am doing,

1] Sent one request to get session variable

```
interval = setInterval(function () {
        $.getJSON('/importProgress', function (data) {
            $('#putProgressPercent').html(data['progressPercent'] + "%");
            $('#putProgressPercentMessage').html(data['progressMessage'] );
            $("#progressBarLine").css("width", data['progressPercent'] + "%");

            if (data['progressPercent'] == 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                $("#loaderModal").hide(); // hide div
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Initially will get 0, but when other (below) request is processing  will get percentage

2] Send other request for data submission on backend side (in my case with for loop) like below

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: "/storeData",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'someValue': someVaribaleToProcress,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var returnDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if (returnDetails['error']) {
                alert(returnDetails['error']);
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
```

and on back side this processes as below :

```
$chunksData = array_chunk($myData,3);
foreach ($chunksData as $index => $oneChunkData) {
        foreach ($oneChunkData as $oneIndex => $details) {
                $isImported = ImportData::addImportData($variables_1, $variables_2);
            }
        $parsedChunk += sizeof($oneChunkData);
        $completedPercent = (round(($parsedChunk * 100) / sizeof($getTempTableData)));
        echo $completedPercent. " : is percent <br>";
        session()->put('importProgress', $completedPercent);
        session()->save();
    }
}
```

This $myData is huge. (suppose 1k now).
Now the problem is until this above for loop (of putting data in db) is completed, the interval hits are in pending state. so not getting updated with data.
even above line of printing percentage (echo $completedPercent. " : is percent";) is also not printing output until all data is processed.
can someone give me solution for this?

Comment: I think that until the loop has ended, the sessions are not written, have you try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php in the loop ?

Comment: You need to look into the Laravel queue system: perform the long running job there. Than have that job sent broadcast events with progress info, look into the documentation about broadcasting. Than have your frontend listen for broadcasted messages. In other words: make your backend actively speak to your frontend, instead of your frontend continuously asking your backend about the progress status.